# Add ajax to rails no database form calculator

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I trying to add ajax to rails no database form calculator. But it seams to not responding. It gives me 204 no content server answer. I trying to solve this issue, but i'm stuck. My JavaScript knowledge is very basic, so detailed response would be very helpful. Without ajax it works fine and pass all tests.

calculator controller

```
class InterestCalculatorController
  def new        
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render 'index.html.erb' }
      format.js 
    end 

    # If accepted parameter is integer, then it shows in view as 5, when it
    # is float, it shows as 5.1  
    @first_0   = params[:a_0].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:a_0].to_f : params[:a_0].to_i
    @second_0  = params[:b_0].to_f % 1 != 0 ? params[:b_0].to_f : params[:b_0].to_i

    # How many percent is number from the number 
    number_to_number(@first_0, @second_0) 

 private 

   def number_to_number(a = 0, b = 0)   
    # If the first number is zero, it sends 0% answer. If the second number is zero 
    # and the first number is nonzero, it sends infinity. Otherwise simple formula calculation.
    if a.zero?
      @result_0 = 0
    elsif b.zero?
      @result_0 = "infinity"
    else
      @result_0 = a.to_f / b.to_f * 100
    end  
  end
end
```

index.js.erb

```
document.getElementById("answer_0").innerHTML = <%= @result_0 %>
```

view index.html.erb

```
<h1>Interest Calculator</h1>

<div id="interest_calculator_main">
  <div id="interest_calculator">
    <%= form_for :interest_calculator, url: { action: :new }, method: :get, remote: true do |f|   %>
      <p>Сколько % составляет число</p>
      <%= number_field_tag :a_0, params[:a_0], step: :any, id: "first_number_0" %>
      <p>от числа</p>
      <%= number_field_tag :b_0, params[:b_0], step: :any, id: "second_number_0" %>
      <%= f.submit 'Calculate!', id: "number_to_number" %>
    <% end %>

    <% unless @result_0.nil? %>
      <p>Number <%= @first_0 %> from number <%= @second_0 %> = <label id="answer_0">%</label></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is being submitted to `new` action, but you have no template for that action (i.e `new.js.erb`), so you get a `204 No Content` response, which should show the following in your server logs:

> No template found for InterestCalculatorController#new

Rename `index.js.erb` to `new.js.erb`, and you will no longer get that error.

---

Also (not related to this error), you may wan't to change `<%= @result_0 %>` to `"<%= @result_0 %>"` in your now `new.js.erb` file:

```
document.getElementById("answer_0").innerHTML = "<%= @result_0 %>"
```

Otherwise your code will throw another error when `@result_0` is set to `"infinity"`.

Comment: After renaming it gives me another error - 304 not modified

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov Could you show the error from your server logs?

Comment: My rails console shows me no error, but mozilla sends me 304 error, and there is   no result_0 answer in template.

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov Please share your `index` action from controller.

Comment: @Garry as far as I know index template is processed by default, so i do not have index action in my controller. I do not plan to add another templates to InterestCalculator controller. So I decide to call it index.

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov Yes, that is true, but since you `@result_0` will be `nil` then the element `<label id="answer_0">` will no exist in the DOM, so `document.getElementById("answer_0").innerHTML` will not work, since the element is `undefined`. Try adding an `index` action to your controller with `@result_0 = 0` and see if that works.

Comment: It works with your suggestion about set default value to '@result_0' in 'index' action. But it behaves very strange, looks like it make some cashing, and my calculations are saved in view, when I reload the page they still the same. And as a bonus, '@first_0' and '@second_0' do not shows in result anymore.

Comment: What do you mean by "make some cashing?"

Comment: @Garry LOL caching i mean, sorry for my mistake, english is not my native language

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145804/discussion-between-gerry-and-kirill-zhuravlov).